# Visual Studio 2017 Community Installation issue

Tags: automated-testing

I have installed Community edition 2017 , i cant locate Console Application under File-> New -> Project.

I can see below.
Under Windows Desktop -> WPF App (.NET Framework)
                       ->WPF User Control Library(.NET Framework)

Comment: I think you have missed some check-boxes when install your configuration.

Comment: i have checked two check boxes as per instructions in Udemy

Comment: and make sure that you are looking under Windows Desktop. (sorry if it's an "is it turned on comment", but seen a lot of people that have missed that in the past)

Comment: @user42654 better add more details to your question. For example what was the full set of options and which you did select.

Comment: Yes i am looking under WIndows Desktop Only. I see only two options. WPF APP and WPF User Control Libraray

Comment: Can any one help with Community setup for download

Comment: ah, it's not there by default.  this isn't really a testing question.  how about we take this to chat

Comment: Sure we can take it to chat to resolve at the earliest. Please guide me how to navigate i will post the question on CHAT.

Comment: if i install Visual Studio Community version 2015 will it show Console Application  option under File ->New ->Projects .Can anyone help on this query pls

Answer (score 1):

Check this official tutorial:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2017

Pay attention to Step 4 where you should select Desktop Development item in order to be able to develop desktop command line applications.

[image]